# How to install an OSX application from source

Tags: macos, build, installation

Normally when I install OSX applications I just use the .dmg but I'm trying to install this application from source that I got from here.

http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus

I cloned the git repository shown on that page. I did

```
git clone https://github.com/sveinbjornt/Platypus
```

After I cloned the directory I didn't find a configure script. The usual way of building and installing things in Linux doesn't seem applicable here. But I was able to successfully compile the source in X-code 4.

Now what? How do I get this application installed on my system? I know that the build succeeded but I don't even know what was built. If I could find an .app file that I could just drag and drop into the Applications folder I guess that would do it, but I didn't see an .app file in the directory.

Comment: Did you try running [`Platypus/Scripts/InstallCommandLineTool.sh`](https://github.com/sveinbjornt/Platypus/blob/master/Scripts/InstallCommandLineTool.sh)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to select "Archive" from the Product menu, then you can export the application bundle to disk.  But why build Platypus from scratch?  Why not just use the official release build, available at http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus ?